# RxJava update data after first Completable but before returning next single

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

What I need to do is make a completable call (verify session token), then once that is complete, update the session token in the next request (returning the last call, which is a single).

This is what I have so far, which does the job, but it looks messy. There has to be a cleaner way to do this? 
I'm looking for a solution similar to how flatmap() works but I want to return the last single.

```
Single<ItemsResponse> getItems() {

    return verifySessionBeforeApiRequest().andThen
    (Completable.create(new CompletableOnSubscribe() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(CompletableEmitter e) throws Exception {
            nextRequest.setSession(getSessionId());
            e.onComplete();
        }
    })).andThen(makeFinalCall(nextRequest));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better/cleaner solution. Instead of verifySessionBeforeApiRequest() returning a Completable, I changed my thought process and made it return a Single which contains the current or new sessionID(if needed). Looks like this.

```
 public Single<ItemsResponse> getItems() {
    return verifySessionBeforeApi().flatMap(new Function<String, SingleSource
            <? extends ItemsResponse>>() {
        @Override
        public SingleSource<? extends ItemsResponse> apply(String sessionId)
                throws Exception {
            return makeFinalCall(new nextRequest(sessionId));
        }
    });
}
```